# How to smooth out an area?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

I have this thing:
[image]

How can I smooth out these parts? (they sort of look blocky, if you get what I mean)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do that by @Hrishav Saha's solution

at first I tried editing those areas but due to the very high amount of verticies, It was impossible (I had frame drops)

I started by selecting the areas that I want to edit: (with circle select)

[image]

if some **verticies are missing**, just press Ctrl + Num+

[image]

Now, to make these areas a separated object (so the amount of verticies will be decreased and we can easily edit them, whether by manually selecting and moving or sculpting) just press **P** and then **Selection**

[image]

and boom! now we can easily edit those areas. if you want to smooth them out just by selecting them, then make sure to use **Proportional Editing**

if not, then just go with sculpting since It's much much easier and more flexible and make sure to use tools such as **Draw, Grab, Smooth, etc.**

when you're done editing, go into **Object Mode**, select both objects and then press **Ctrl + J** for joining them

Alternatively, you can do that by going to **Object -> Join**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This one's pretty simple. Add a *Subdivision Subsurface* modifier!

[image]

And after that, right click on the object and click *Shade Smooth*.

Comment: that's a good solution but unfortunately since I've already applied a few Subdivision Surface modifiers in the past, it now makes no difference. I even added another one right now, no difference :(

Comment: In that case, there's a more, well, manual method. Two, actually. The first is to go into *Edit Mode* and manually smooth our your mesh. The second is to go into *Sculpt Mode*, take the *Smooth* brush, set it to a high radius and low effect, and use it on the jagged edges. Hope it works!